# PyQt - SQLAlchemy doesn't accept QString

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyqt

I'm using PyQt and SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy doesn't accept QStrings. Is there any way to pass QStrings to it or I have to convert QStrings to Python strings every single time?

Thank you.

Here's the code:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class DbUtils(object):
    def __init__(self, db_file = None, parent = None):

        self.db = None
        self.db_connection = None
        self.db_file = str(db_file)

    def db_open(self):
        self.db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + self.db_file)
        self.db_connection = self.db.connect()

    def db_close(self):
        self.db_connection.close()

    def db_create_voltdrop(self):
        metadata = MetaData()

        tb_cable_brands = Table('cable_brands', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('brand', String)
            )
        tb_cable_types = Table('cable_types', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('brand_id', None, ForeignKey('cable_brands.id')),
            Column('type', String),
            Column('alpha', String)
            )
        tb_cable_data = Table('cable_data', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('type_id', None, ForeignKey('cable_types.id')),
            Column('size', String),
            Column('resistance', Float)
            )
        metadata.create_all(self.db)

    def delete_cable_brand(self, cable_brand):
        cable_brand = str(cable_brand)
        metadata = MetaData()
        metadata.bind = self.db

        tb_cable_brands = Table('cable_brands', metadata, autoload = True)

        cable_brands = select([tb_cable_brands.c.brand],
                          and_(tb_cable_brands.c.brand == cable_brand)
                          )
        row = self.db_connection.execute(cable_brands)
        data = row.fetchone()
        if str(data[0]) == cable_brand:
            cable_brands = tb_cable_brands.delete().where(tb_cable_brands.c.brand == cable_brand)
            self.db_connection.execute(cable_brands)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: You have two questions; please ask them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [change the API to v2](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html) and PyQt will always use regular Python strings instead of `QString`s.

**Edit**

*Case 1*: Without `sip.setapi`

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
c = QtGui.QComboBox()
c.addItems(["one","two"])
print c.currentText(), type(c.currentText())
c.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

# Outputs
one <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>
```

*Case 2*: With `sip.setapi`

```
import sip
sip.setapi("QString",2)

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
c = QtGui.QComboBox()
c.addItems(["one","two"])
print c.currentText(), type(c.currentText())
c.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

# Outputs
one <type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: If I use sip.setapi('QString', 1), it says "AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'get_dialect'". If I use sip.setapi('QString', 2), it says "ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1". And if I don't use sip and I convert QString to Python str(db_file), db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + self.db_file), then everything works fine. But I don't want to convert all QStrings to str every time.

Comment: @user665327: You need to set the API to v2 *before* the first time you import PyQt4. If you do it after, you'll get that error.

Comment: I know, I've put it above all other imports and still have these errors.

Comment: @user665327: This works fine here. Of course, it doesn't do anything. Is this the only place you import PyQt? I mean, you might have another 'main' file where you setup `QApplication` and import this module/class? If so, `sip.setapi` should go there.

Comment: If I put it in the main module where QApplication is and use QString with SQLAlchemy, it again gives me this: "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type." If I use str(QString) - it works fine.

Comment: @user665327: That does not make sense. Where do you get that QString from? I mean is it possible that it might not be a QString? Or SQLAlchemy might have a problem with unicode literals. Changing str(QString), unicode(QString) make any difference?

Comment: I've added a delete_cable_brand() to the code above. It takes a string as an argument. If I pass a straight QString 'cable_brand' (which is a text from a QComboBox), it gives me that error. If I use 'str(cable_brand)' - no error. unicode(cable_brand) will be the same. But what I want is to pass QString without converting them to Python strings all the time (some of my functions take 5-6 string arguments and I have tens of such functions).

Comment: @user665327: Can you post the full traceback when you use `sip.setapi` and don't convert to `str` or `unicode`? If `cable_brand` is originally a `QString`, after `setapi` call it will be a unicode string. That should work unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: It's too big for a comment. Here's the last bit: Traceback (most recent call last):
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'SELECT cable_brands.brand \nFROM cable_brands \nWHERE cable_brands.brand = ?' (PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'bndfndfn'),)
Exit code:  0

Comment: @user665327: Either you didn't put `sip.setapi("QString",2)` at the beginning or that error doesn't make sense at all. After you set the API to 2 you shouldn't get any `QString`s. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Well, now it says "NameError: name 'QString' is not defined" in another module. And if I put that sip import into my module, it says "ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1"

Comment: @user665327: With API 2, there is no longer a `QString`. So any `QtCore.QString` call is unnecessary and (as you saw) invalid. You can and should pass regular strings there. Hmm, now you have a side to choose. Either pick API 2 and remove all those `QtCore.QString` calls, or you continue with API 1 and cast `QString`s to `str` like you were doing before.

Comment: Ok, I'll probably go with the API 2 and replace all 'QString' for 'str'. What about QStringList? Do I have to replace it with '[]'? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: O-oh! How can I do this then: setStyleSheet(QtCore.QString.fromUtf8("font-family: Sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; font-weight: bold;"))? QString is not recognized anymore. [SOLVED] Got it! use unicode() instead.

Comment: @user665327: I don't think you *have to* change them. But in any API, you can already use a list of regular strings wherever you need a `QStringList`. See the [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstringlist.html#details).

Comment: I don't see anything unicode there. This should be fine: `setStyleSheet("font-family: Sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; font-weight: bold;")`. If you have unicode things, just use `u"unicode stringy"`

Comment: Well, now I have "TypeError: QComboBox.addItems(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'". What's the Python equivalent of QStringList? If I don't change them, it says ""NameError: name 'QStringList' is not defined"". Thanks

Comment: @user665327: see the examples in my answer :).

Comment: It was a different error, I was pulling floats from the database (I deleted 'str' from 'str(row[0])' by mistake) and putting them into my list and then tried to add it to a combo box, so it was complaining. But I understood the error description as it didn't like my Python list instead of the former QStringList. It's all good now. Thank you.